# Why can't I link a mixed C/C++ static library that has a C interface using gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a mixed C/C++ library.

On the outside it provides a C interface using extern C. Internally there are templates and classes. Creating the library with "ar" posed no problems.  The file is called libo-client.a.

However, when linking the `.a` file using gcc (not g++) I get lots of errors that look like this:

```
libo-client.a(mysocket.o):(.rodata._ZTV7mStream[vtable for mStream]+0x10): undefined reference to `__cxa_pure_virtual'
...
mysocket.cpp:(.text+0x15ad): undefined reference to `operator new[](unsigned long)'
mysocket.cpp:(.text+0x15c1): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
mysocket.cpp:(.text+0x167a): undefined reference to `__cxa_allocate_exception'
mysocket.cpp:(.text+0x16a6): undefined reference to `__cxa_throw'
...
```

My compile/link line looks like this:

```
gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) test2.c libo-client.a -o test2
```

Where test2 is my test harness.

This problem does not occur when I'm using g++.  However, I'm going to interface this library into C project which is compiled with gcc. How do I get around this? What's the cause of it?

**EDIT:**

Even though I'm not using the standard C++ library it's obviously needing some things like operator new/delete etc. and there are exceptions internally.

I'm linking this thing against the Xen hypervisor so I'm not sure what options i have but to totally rewrite this thing or perhaps try compiling Xen with G++ instead?

Comment: Making it a dynamic library might also help. Have you looked into that at all?

Comment: Thanks Chris.  That actually works as a dynamic shared object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way around your problem it is to link with `g++`; this gets the correct libraries in place.

The problem is that C++ has a lot of requirements that C does not, and does more work before calling `main()` to ensure that things are properly initialized.

If you insist on linking with the C compiler, at the very least you'd have to include the C++ support library in with your link command.

Comment: +1 - including a C++ library in a C project will take more than just throwing the object files at it.

Comment: Switching to g++ fixed it for me too, but is there a more portable way?  How would I write a Makefile for a non-Linux system?

Comment: @EdwardFalk: More portable than linking a (partially) C++ program with a C++ compiler?  No; that will be the most portable way to do it.  The alternative is working out how the C++ compiler invokes the linker to get the C++ stuff done, and then work out how to twist the C compiler into invoking the linker in the same way that the C++ compiler does automatically for you.  Be my guest if you want to try, but it will be radically harder to do, and vastly less portable.

Comment: What if the compiler isn't named "g++".  Gnu isn't the only compiler out there.  Is there a ${CC++} macro in make, equivalent to ${CC}?

Comment: It's usually denoted by the macro `${CXX}`.  Where your C compiler is `gcc`, the C++ compiler is usually `g++`.  Where you're using different compilers, you still link with the C++ compiler that was used to build the C++ object modules.

Comment: Perfect; that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Your C++ library is still a C++ library internally, which means that it contains external references to various housekeeping functions from C++ standard library. In order to resolve these links you'll have to link your final executable for C++ standard library. `gcc` does not do it for you automatically. Either explicitly supply the C++ standard library to `gcc`, or use `g++` compiler instead.

Answer (score 1):

An archive is still just a bunch of object files (.o), so when linking them into an executable or shared library, you still need to link with `g++` to resolve symbols to the C++ runtime (like the once you see in your error messages).

For your C functions to have C-linkage, it should be enough to wrap them in `extern "C"` blocks. Things might get more complicated on, e.g. Windows, with it's myriads of linkage macros (STDCALL, WINAPI, etc.) that expand to other stuff (some compiler specific) like __stdcall, __declspec(export), etc.

Answer (score 1):

The errors which you see seem to appear due to missing linkage to Standard C++ library which has the symbol definition for operator new, operator delete etc. Try linking `stdc++` say `gcc $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) test2.c libo-client.a -o test2 -lstdc++`. Better option is as suggested by Jonathan Leffler to use `g++` instead of `gcc`

Answer (score 0):

Writing stuff in C++ that can be used from C without any of the extras C++ requires is *very hard*. Probably even compiler dependent. Your library requires the C++ runtime, and to initialize the C++ runtime presumaby requires special support before caling main() in your program. Your chimaera in still a C++ program when you link in C files, even if it is main() and everything else outside your library.